# MSBuild - multiple errors stating projects are not part of a namespace

Tags: msbuild

I'm running MSBuild 4.0 against my .net 4.0 solution  and I am getting a lot of error similar to the following:

```
"E:\Hudson\jobs\HCIM 7.0.0\workspace\7.0.0\HCIM_Dev\BC_HCIM.msbuild" (default target) (1) ->
"E:\Hudson\jobs\HCIM 7.0.0\workspace\7.0.0\HCIM_Dev\BC_HCIM.sln" (Build target) (2:2) ->
"E:\Hudson\jobs\HCIM 7.0.0\workspace\7.0.0\HCIM_Dev\src\Common\HCIM.Distribution.Service\HCIM.Distribution.Service.csproj" (default target) (46:3) ->
(CoreCompile target) -> 
  DistributionProcessor.cs(6,32): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Distribution' does not exist in the namespace 'HCIM.BusinessTransaction' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [E:\Hudson\jobs\HCIM 7.0.0\workspace\7.0.0\HCIM_Dev\src\Common\HCIM.Distribution.Service\HCIM.Distribution.Service.csproj]
```

When I build this in the IDE, it compiles fine (VS 2015, VS 2013), however on Jenkins and when I locally run my script, these are the errors that comes up.

Looking at the IDE and the .csproj files I see that these assemblies are referenced accordingly.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an msbuild and/or framework version issue. Here's a few things to check:

- What framework version are your projects referencing? Maybe one is targeting a higher version than 4.0
- Make sure this framework version is installed on build server.
- Try adjusting your script to use the same msbuild version as the IDE

Note Msbuild is [not part of the framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh162058.aspx) since VS2013 but a separate download is [available](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760) for running on your build server.